# cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection'

Tags: dependency-injection

Getting the following error when launching asp.net core 6.0 c# web application. Application did not through any run time error. it just displays 404: page not found. Unable to launch the home page. I noticed the following issue in IServiceCollection object when debugging through Startup.cs page

((System.RuntimeType)(new Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection.ServiceCollectionDebugView(services).Items[12]).ImplementationType).DeclaringMethod = error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection'

I tried to resolve the issue but still not able to fix.

Comment: Please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without such example, it will be very difficult for us to provide you with any meaningful answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.